# Why the following ffmpeg command outpus an eleven minutes long video?

Tags: ffmpeg

Why the following ffmpeg command outpus an eleven minutes long video?

```
 ffmpeg -ss 600 -i 01x01TheStrongestMan.mp4 -to 660 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y outputxxx.mp4
```

I want to slice the video from the 600 second to the 660 second, the output should be a 1 minute long video.
How can I do that and why my command is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Both `-ss` and `-to` should be on same side of input. Place `-to` before `-i`.

Comment: @Gyan actually both -ss and -to should be after -i
Post your answer and I will choose it as the accepted one.

Comment: Not necessary. The accuracy is different as the frame seeking method is different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few little test examples I did which may shed some light.

Seek before: (Quicker but less accurate)

```
ffmpeg -ss 600 -to 660 -i movie.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y output1.mp4
```

Seek after: (Slower but more accurate)

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -ss 600 -to 660 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y output2.mp4
```

Seek before and after: (Quick and accurate)

```
ffmpeg -ss 500 -i movie.mkv -ss 100 -to 160 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y output3.mp4
```

> However........

Depending on which frames are which, you'll not always get accurate cuts/trims. You'll also get different results, or find one method better than another, depending on whether you are just copying streams, or encoding.